# How to avoid redundant steps in calculation of number of permutations?

Tags: python, algorithm, function, math, permutation

How can I make the following script more intelligent, like a human would do it?

(avoiding the redundant calculations of the full factorials)

```
def combinations_without_repetition(n, r):
    return (factorial(n) / (factorial(r) * (factorial(n - r))))
combinations_without_repetition(10, 5)
```

(I get errors: Too large values.)

Comment: Please paste code as code, not as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [scipy.special.comb](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.comb.html#scipy.special.comb) for this. Switching `exact` to `True` gives the exact answer as an integer at the cost of speed.

```
>>> from scipy.special import comb
>>> comb(10, 5, exact=False, repetition=False)
252.0
>>> comb(10, 5, exact=True, repetition=False)
252
```